# Can't upload files with CraueFormFlowBundle

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, craueformflow

I am trying to upload a file in a multi-step form with [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle).

Everything is working fine, but at the end of the process, my entity never get updated with file path as it used to work before

Here is basically what I am trying to do :

```php
// FormType

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    switch ($options['flowStep']) {
        case 1:
            $builder->add('username', 'text', array('label'=>'Votre pseudo','required'=>false))
                ->add('file','file', array('label'=>'Photo de profil','required'=>false));
            break;
// ....
```

While my entity is set up like this :

```php
/**
 * Ray\CentralBundle\Entity\Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="clients")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ray\CentralBundle\Entity\ClientRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Client implements UserInterface
{
    private $filenameForRemove;

    /**
     * @var string $username
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var file $file
     *
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    public $file;

    // ...
```

It seems that when `$flow->saveCurrentStepData();` is called, `$form['file']` is filled and point to the temp file.

What I don't get, is why on the next step, the file value won't get stored in the session.

I've extended the `getSessionData()` method of `Craue\FormFlowBundle\Form\FormFlow` like this :

```php
protected function getSessionData() {

    var_dump($this->session->get($this->sessionDataKey, array()));

    return $this->session->get($this->sessionDataKey, array());
}
```

This is giving me all the form data except the "file" one, as expected...

How to get file upload to works with this bundle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you cant store files in the session...

here a possibility to manage it..

Controller

```
// ...
if ($flow->isValid($form)) {
    $data = $request->request->get($form->getName(), array());

    // upload the entity (Event) main picture
    if ($event->preUpload() && $picture = $event->upload()) {
        $data['picture'] = $picture;
    }


    // save form progress
    $flow->saveCurrentStepData($data);
// ...
```

Entity Event

```
// ...

public function preUpload()
{
    if(null !== $this->picturefile)
    {
        $this->picture = uniqid() . '.' . $this->picturefile->guessExtension();
        return $this->picture;
    }
}
```

And you have to overwrite the FormFlow method saveCurrentStepData() ... (with a custom Bundle with getParent)

```
public function saveCurrentStepData($data = false) {
    $sessionData = $this->getSessionData();
    $sessionData[$this->currentStep] = $data ? $data : $this->request->request->get($this->formType->getName(), array()) ;
    $this->setSessionData($sessionData);
}
```

Comment: I finally understood the situation last late night, and have done it otherwise : persisting some data right after the first step. This is forcing me to change the form design, and have all non nullable values on the first step, next steps are just an option. My solution fits my needs, but I'll accept yours and maybe make another one as an alternative later. Thanks.